# How to fix the error 'Failed to create appdomain ssisdb.dbo[runtime].x'?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I am trying to deploy an SSIS 2012 project to an SSIS Catalog on a newly built SQL Server machine. It throws an error with the following message whilst creating the folder.

```
Failed to create appdomain ssisdb.dbo[runtime].6.
```

Trying to create the folder through SSMS alsos throws the same error, but with     `ssisdb.dbo[runtime].7`

I enabled CLR on the instance, and now it throws the same error on `ssisdb.dbo[runtime].9`

I have tried running the `create_folder proc` - same error and SQL Server will not let me step into the proc.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: @siva - thanks but cant see it. server is 12gb ram with only 2.5 in use. its a brand new box, im the only one using it. the error is not when running a package, just tring to create a folder in the catalog

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some searches on the web reveal that there are related issues reported on Microsoft Connect website. Microsoft suggest that this could be due to a recent installation of CLR/.NET related patch, where the system reboot is pending. Try rebooting the server and then create the *SSISDB* catalog.

[*Failed to create AppDomain "master.sys[runtime].X"*](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/693184/failed-to-create-appdomain-master-sys-runtime-x)

#### Quoted from Microsoft Connect website:

Errors like:

```
Msg 6517, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
AppDomain "MDS.dbo [runtime] .20" Could not create.
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

come directly from .NET/CLR itself. It's usually about some inconsistency with the CLR/.NET itself. It means the CLR installation is corrupted (unlikely), or, more likely, a .NET patch was recently installed and the machine is pending a reboot.

Let us know if reboot doesn't fix the problem.

About the upgrade failure from upgrade step 677 to 678: this issue is fixed in Denali RC1.

Comment: work around was to hack the insert statment from the create folder sp. this worked but deployment failed, restarted db engine service, and it worked. no permissions to restart box. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You just have to reboot sql server services and it's done.

Comment: In my case, the restart of SQL released some memory, which fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for a day and after updating my windows and .NET frameworks 
problem disappeared.the problem relates to .Net framework try to repair it.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in one of SQL SSIS jobs. Many jobs had failed with same error.
When I checked the recent installations, I saw that DOTNET was installed and the server hadn't completely rebooted after that. I rebooted the server and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a pending .NET update waiting for a restart and it interfered with by .NET web application as well as with SSIS. Restarting the server and fully installing the update fixed our issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error today and it was fixed by simply repairing the SQL Server by using simple going to C:\SQL2022\Developer_ENU and opening the SETUP.EXE and going to Maintenance and it solved the problem for me.